# spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging 4.1.x depends on outdated artifacts javax.annotation-api as well as org.apache.httpcomponents 4

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-ee, spring-cloud-gcp, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am currently trying to update our Spring Boot Applications to Spring Boot 3.0.5.
Accordingly I am trying to migrate to Spring Cloud GCP version 4.1.4, which according to their [readme](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp#compatibility-with-spring-project-versions) on github is intended to be compatible with Spring Boot 3.x.

However their Starter [spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging/4.1.4) in version 4.1.4 depends on:

- [spring-cloud-gcp-logging artifact version 4.1.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/spring-cloud-gcp-logging/4.1.4) which depends on ->
- [google-cloud-logging-logback version 0.130.9-alpha](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-logging-logback/0.130.9-alpha) which in turn depends on ->

  - org.apache.httpcomponents » httpclient version 4.5.14,
  - org.apache.httpcomponents » httpcore version 4.4.16 and
  - javax.annotation » javax.annotation-api version 1.3.2

(Sorry Stackoverflow only lets me post up to 8 links appearantly, but you can access all these artifacts through the above link to google-cloud-logging-logback/0.130.9-alpha)

Now as to my understanding, as Spring Boot 3.x uses Java 17 all javax packages should be replaced by their jakarta alternatives, in this case javax.annotation-api should be replaced with [jakarta.annotation-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.annotation/jakarta.annotation-api) (actually since Java 11 already right?)

Also to my understanding, the apache httpcomponents 4.x artifacts should be replaced with their [apache httpcomponents.core5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.core5/httpcore5) and [apache httpcomponents.client5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.client5/httpclient5) counterparts.

Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding or missing something?

Comment: The fact that Spring doesn't support HTTP client 4.x doesn't mean other libraries still cannot use that. So unless you are using it yourself there is nothing in there that is blatently wrong. I'm also not sure what the problem is you have? DOesn't it work? Does it break?

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum for your reply!
No it does not break per say, but I keep having external libraries in my projects that are outdated. As part of the upgrade process I am looking through the external libraries of my projects and try to eleminate any outdated/deprecated dependencies. Having http components 4 and javax in my dependancy tree from this one dependancy when everything else uses 5 and jakarta just seems unclean/error prone to me.

Comment: Well apparently Google Cloud needs that. As stated the fact that Spring doesn't use it doesn't mean others don't.